# Rooting/unlocking Android Nexus One with broken power button using Linux terminal tools

Tags: rooting, adb, nexus-one, rom-manager, superuser

I am attempting to get Cyanogenmod onto my Nexus One, but am running into far more problems than expected.  The information on rooting Android devices seems heavily fragmented across the web and the tools unreliable.  At least in my case, *SuperOneClick* has proven a complete misnomer.  So I'd like to go back to basics - executing as many of the commands as possible from a Linux terminal to get the phone rooted/unlocked/whatever else has to happen to get Cyanogenmod installed.  The two constraints I'm working with here are as follows:

1. The device is running Android `2.2.1` (I downgraded from `2.3.x` using the `PASSIMG` method).
2. The power button on the device is broken, so any method which requires pressing/holding it is ruled out.

The problem I am having is that even after following Linux-centric guides, I get to the point of installing the [SuperUser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su&hl=en) app followed by the [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en) app, but I'm never prompted to give ROM Manager superuser permissions and so can't flash the ClockworkMod recovery.

Below I describe the steps I've been taking so far, based on the [How To Root Nexus One Running Android 2.2.1 From Ubuntu Linux](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-nexus-one-running-android-2-2-1-from-ubuntu-linux/) guide.

- Download/extract/move [Nexus One Softroot files](http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/nexus_one_softroot.tar) to same directory as `adb`
- From `adb` directory, execute the following commands:

  sudo ./adb push psneuter /data/local/tmp/psneuter
  sudo ./adb push busybox /data/local/tmp/busybox
  sudo ./adb push su /data/local/tmp/su
  sudo ./adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/psneuter
  sudo ./adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox
  sudo ./adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/su
  sudo ./adb shell cd /data/local/tmp ./psneuter
  sudo ./adb shell

After executing `sudo ./adb shell` as above, I get the `#` prompt, which is purported to indicate that rooting was successful.

- Still following the guide, I then execute the commands which purportedly make root permanent:

  mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
  cd /data/local/tmp
  ./busybox cp busybox /system/bin
  chmod 4755 /system/bin/busybox
  busybox cp su /system/bin
  chmod 4755 /system/bin/su
  exit
  exit
- Again, still following the guide, I execute the commands which purportedly set the `/system` partition back to read-only:

  sudo ./adb shell
  su
  mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
  exit
  exit
- Now, I download the *SuperUser* app from the Android Market and open it to make sure it's running.
- Next, I download the ROM Manager app from Google Play (looks like it pulled a sneaky and upgraded from Android Market to Google Play here).
- I run ROM Manager and choose *Flash ClockworkMod Recovery*.  I'm prompted to confirm the phone is a Google Nexus One and then ROM Manager runs for about 30 seconds (yellow program bar goes all the way) before spitting out *An error occurred while attempting to run privileged commands!*.  And this is the point I am stuck at.

I should note that at no point am I prompted by the SuperUser app to give the ROM Manager app super user permissions.  I don't restart the phone or do anything else throughout all of the steps I've described above, so I can't see any reason for root to have been lost at any point.  In fact, if I execute the command `sudo ./adb shell` after all this, I still get the `#` prompt indicating root.  And when I execute `id` afterwards, I get `uid=0(root) gid=0(root)` -- further confirmation of root.  I really am stuck on this one.  I've spent a lot of time digging through forum posts and online articles, but the signal to noise ratio is poor and I haven't been able to find anything that actually works.  Can someone suggest where I am going wrong?