# How can I root my TCL Idol X (S950) with Linux?

Tags: rooting, linux

I have a TCL Idol X (S950) phone and I found out that I can root in using 'V-Root' (a Chinese software) however the software is for Windows.

The problem is that I don't have Windows, more explanation at the end.

**More in detail:**

V-Root is this soft: http://www.mgyun.com

If I well understood ([Rooting/unlocking Android Nexus One with broken power button using Linux terminal tools](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33060/rooting-unlocking-android-nexus-one-with-broken-power-button-using-linux-termina)) the rooting usually just install `su` command using some vulnerability in the Linux Kernel or in a daemon ... or any other similar vulnerability in the Android OS.

**Reason**
You may wonder why I'm not just grab a Windows pc from one of my friend and in my opinion there are a couple of reason for this:

- Android (or better Android/Linux ) is using Linux kernel so in make sense to have some standard procedure to root on Linux too
- Many of the Win. Root solution are shipped with some custom soft that we can not really trust ( for example V-Root, beside the fact that is in Chinese and few people non-chinese can understand it, how can I trust that it is not doing any malicious operation on my phone ? )
- Most of the tutorial/forum thread are Windows oriented, so there are few and spare info related to Linux

**So my question:**
Is there a possibility to achieve the above on Linux? If not, is there any other method I can use on Linux?

Comment: To me this looks like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192154): Is your issue that you want to use that specific software to achieve *something* – or do you want to root the device?

Comment: Sorry maybe it is not clear, I want to root my phone just that

Comment: OK, tnx: I edited your question to make that more clear − and also linked to it from our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575), which you might wish to check (as it also mentions some independent methods, some of them supporting Linux, as e.g. [Root Many Android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460)).